# Pass Bootstrap Card Object to New Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, api, web-applications

Experience Level = beginner. I'm attempting to make a web application which uses an API to load data on a page. The user initially selects a State which is then used in the API call to retrieve all lakes in that state. The lakes data is populated on individual bootstrap cards with some of the lake data. When the user click on the bootstrap card, I want to get the lake objectID which was previously returned by the initial API call then use that objectID in another API call to get specifics on the lake. Have spent way too many hours trying to find out how. I think I need to use onclick this.form something something...on the results page. Thanks!

Initial Search Where User Selects State:

```
<% include ./partials/header %>
<div class="row">
        <div style="width: 50%; margin: 25px auto">
        <form action="/results" method="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectState">Choose a State to View Lakes</label>
            <select name="state" size="8" class="form-control" id="selectState">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MI">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

            </select>    
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Submit Takes User to the Results Page:**

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

 <div class="container">
     <header class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container text-center">
             <h1>Select a Lake to View Additional Information and Do Something with Notifications and Alerts</h1>
             <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/search">Back To Search</a>
             </p>
         </div>
     </header>
        <div class="album py-3 bg-light">
            <div class="container">

              <div class="row">
                   <% data["features"].forEach(function(lake){ %>

                <div class="col-md-4 card-group">
                  <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                     <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                      <form action="/results/details" method="GET">
                        <div class="form-group">
                      <p class="card-text">Lake ID - <%= lake["attributes"]["lakeid"] %></p>
                      <p class="card-text">Location - <%= lake["attributes"]["location"] %></p>
                      <p class="card-text hide">State - <%= lake["attributes"]["state"] %></p>
                      <p class="card-text">Latitude - <%= lake["attributes"]["latitude"] %></p>
                      <p class="card-text">Longitude - <%= lake["attributes"]["longitude"] %></p>
                      <p class="card-text">Object ID - <%= lake["attributes"]["objectid"] %></p>
                      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-end mt-auto">

                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <% }) %>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
  </div> 
<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had to add a form element that had a value of the objectid so it would pass to the new route when I submitted the form. It works but probably not the most accurate way to do it. Still learning....